# Why does Unity's Legacy Vertex Lit disable my code that sets the color of tiles on a 2D tile map?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To start, I have a bird eye view 2d tilemap that I generate procedural. I color each tile using TileMap.SetColor( new Color(r,g,b,a));. This works very well with the default shader that does not process light on the scene. I want light in my game, so I swapped the shader, 1 by 1, to every other shader with none supporting the custom color and lighting at the same time in Legacy vertex Lit Mode. I tried swapping my rendering mode to Forward and Deffered and this did work as I had my custom colors on top of the lighting, but problems occurred. The reason I swapped to Vertex Lit in the first place was because I was getting artifacts at the boundaries of every tile with lines that showed the cross sections of tiles that overlapped and I get a way lower frame rate in forward/deffered, so I prefer legacy. I know why the shader does this and I tried writing my own, but I am very new to Unity, so I am not experience enough to dive into graphics that far.

What Is Needed: All that is needed is my custom tile colors and lighting in Legacy Vertex Lit mode or A fix to the overlapping tiles lighting up in forward and deffered modes.

Thanks again for the help! I am losing my mind trying to solve this.

EDIT: I noticed that when I changed the layer or z position of a tile in that map, the effect disappeared completely in forward and deffered of just that tile only. I don't know if this the solution I am looking for, but its a start.

EDIT #2: I set the chunk rendering mode to individual and it fixes the problem as in the first edit, but performance takes a very big hit. Any way to tell the render/shader that each tile is separated?

Comment: So you want to light up a 2D plane; how exactly does that work?

Comment: Basically, I have a 2D tilemap, then I make a point light source and move it to -1 in z plane. Now, it can light up the map and it looks really nice. In vertex lit it barely hinders performance too.

Comment: So you just want a vignette? You could probably do that with a texture, either on the plane or attached to the camera.

Comment: Well, I have lava and things that light up the map and towers that their projectiles emit light. I also color the tiles according to perlin noise to show variances in the tilemap. Its getting to the point where I might as well make a new tilemap layer and just 1/8 alpha grey tint and make it less or more alpha according to perlin variances, but I didn't want to go this way. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I eventually got it to work. What I did to get rid of the lines and get custom coloring in the game was to swap rendering modes to forward mode. Then, you can go into the shader you are using for the tilemap and add #pragma noforwardadd.